# Can't debug node application on remote server

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm running express app on remote server (my-domain.com) like that:

```
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./server.js
```

In `intellij idea` i've setup `debug configuration (Attach Node.js/chrome)`:

```
host: my-domain.com
port: 9229
```

When i click `debug` button, i get this error:

> Invalid response from the remote host. Please check the options in the
>   debug configuration

---

I can debug the same application on localhost with this setup:

```
host: localhost
port: 9229
```

Why i can't attach to remote node application and debug it? Can `intellij idea` give me more information about error?

Comment: Are there any messages in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")? Do you use any antivirus software or firewall/proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I found cool way that solves my problem and many others, it has been there for ages and i din't use it! :)

For my particular problem it's possible to use `ssh tunnels`

```
ssh -L 9221:localhost:9229 user@my-domain.com
```

Now i can attach node debugger to localhost:9221. It just forwards all traffic from remote port 9229 to my local 9221.

Another this is **remote port forwarding**:

Just added this line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

Here is

```
ssh -R 9001:localhost:9000 user@my-domain.com
```

Now all traffic on port 9000 on remote machine sent to my local node express application. I can debug, do whatever i want

Here's the article i got ideas from: https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html